# Cordova: Is there a way to detect whether Voice Dictation has ended on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

Please note that this question is for **Cordova/PhoneGap/Hybrid** apps.

I have a `<textarea>` for which I want the app to behave in a certain way only when voice dictation input has ended -- i.e. user tabs "Done". However, this is proving to be rather difficult.

iOS's `UIKit` provides `dictationRecordingDidEnd` event under `UITextInput` but I am not sure if this can even be used in a hybrid app. (iOS Developer Library doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextInput/insertDictationResult:))

EDIT: I am using `ionic-plugin-keyboard`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try to use the [SpeechRecognitionPlugin](https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin) or [cordova-plugin-iflyspeech](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-iflyspeech)

For the `cordova-plugin-iflyspeech` you have 13 events to have control of the voice control in your iOS device like:

```
SpeechBegin
SpeechEnd
SpeechCancel
SpeechResults
SpeechError  
VolumeChanged

SpeakBegin
SpeakPaused
SpeakResumed
SpeakCancel
SpeakCompleted 
SpeakProgress
BufferProgress
```

And has support for a big number of languages like: English (US), English (UK), French, Spanish, Italian, etc.

This is an example of the documentation

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    $('div#status').html( 'speech engine ready' );
}
function startReading() {
    var text = $('textarea#read').val();
    navigator.speech.startSpeaking( text, {voice_name: 'xiaoyan'} );
}
function stopReading() {
    navigator.speech.stopSpeaking();
}
function startListening() {
    $('div#status').html( 'Listening, please speak.' );

    navigator.speech.startListening({language:'en-US'} function(str) {
            // this is what the device hear and understand
            $('textarea#read').val( str );
        });
}
function stopListening() {
    navigator.speech.stopListening();
}
```

And here you can bind the iOS method `dictationRecordingDidEnd` to:
`stopListening();` or `cancelListening();` methods, depending the action.

Comment: I would recommend the cordova-plugin-iflyspeech plugin too.